# Monitoring React/NodeJS/MongoDB application in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, performance, monitoring

I have React/NodeJS/MongoDB application running in AWS and just wondering what is the best way to monitor the application's health and performance. Is it using specialist tools like Dynatrace or using AWS services like CloudWatch Alarms and Application Insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monitoring is a bit of a complex topic, so let's split it into separate sub-topics.

- React. Apparently, you can hardly monitor it since it is on FE, the only thing you can do is integrate something like Sentry into your application and send errors that you got on the FE. (You can integrate same thing into BE, as well, defo won't hurt)
- Node.js. It depends on how you are running your application. e.g. if you are running it on EC2, you can use CloudWatch + some custom metrics to monitor the instance health. If you are using Kube, there are some health checks that Kube can do + monitoring instances on which you are running your cluster. If we are speaking about AWS Lambda... and so on :)
- MongoDB. Again it depends on how you are running it, whether it is an EC2 or Document DB, or maybe you are using MongoDB Atlas...

Overall you can use CloudWatch as a native solution for AWS, alternatively, you could integrate something like NewRelic for metrics, and SumoLogic for logs.